# Django regular expression on success format

Tags: regex, django

Hi I'm trying to integrate a new gateway in to [django-sms-gateway](https://bitbucket.org/schinckel/django-sms-gateway/) but this maybe a regular expression question.

When configuring the gateway it asks for a success_format and states...

> A regular expression that parses the response. May contain named
> groups for "gateway_message_id", "status_message" and "status_code".

The example given is... `ID: (?P<gateway_message_id>.+)`

The gateway I'm trying to integrate with states this as there return parameters ...

> The first line i s a simple heading and shows the names of the 3 col
> umns returned. The second line contains 3 columns, each separated by
> the | (pipe) character.

The return parameters will look like the following:

> error code|error text|submission reference
>
> 0|sms submitted|eb725f96b4b094d5f8318741cc1a545f-2

what would the regular expression be on the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All they are saying is you can define how the success response looks.  If I am understanding correctly, this is what you want:

```
(?P<status_code>[0-9]+)|(?P<status_message>.+)|(?P<gateway_message_id>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)
```